# WebSphere 5.1: Setting JDBC datasource connection as "unshareable"

Tags: websphere, connection-pooling, stateless-session-bean

L.S.

Our DB provider has suggested that we use "unshareable" connections when connecting to their DB. I have a reasonable understanding about the pros/cons of using "unshareable" connections, and our programming model will not cause any issues mentioned in various [blog posts](http://websphere.sys-con.com/node/43291).

Can anyone give me an idea of how to make our JDBC datasource connections "unsharable" without using the web.xml? Our component is an Stateless Session Bean not a Servlet.

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using <res-sharing-scope> element in the <resource-ref> definition in web.xml